# Global variable inside a constructor with PHP

Tags: php, oop, scope

This should be obvious, but I'm getting a bit confused about PHP variable scope.

I have a variable inside a Constructor, which I want to use later in a function in the same class. My current method is this:

```
<?php

class Log(){

   function Log(){
      $_ENV['access'] = true;
   }

   function test(){
      $access = $ENV['access'];
   }

}

?>
```

Is there a better way to do this than abusing environment variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use a class variable, which has a context of... a class :

*(Example for PHP 5, of course ; I've re-written a few things so your code is more PHP5-compliant)*

```
class Log {
   // Declaration of the propery
   protected $_myVar;

   public function __construct() {
      // The property is accessed via $this->nameOfTheProperty :
      $this->_myVar = true;
   }

   public function test() {
      // Once the property has been set in the constructor, it keeps its value for the whole object :
      $access = $this->_myVar;
   }

}
```

You should take a look at :

- [The "Classes and Objects" section of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
- And, for this specific question, the sub-section [Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: I don't think the () after the class is valid...?

Comment: @SeanJA : oh yes, of course, you're right ; I didn't see those when I copy-pasted the code from the OP ;; thanks for your note !

Answer (score 3):

Globals are considered harmful. If this is an outside dependency, pass it through the constructor and save it inside a property for later use. If you need this to be set only during the call to test, you might want to consider making it an argument to that method.

Comment: That is what I said with an example, -1 for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the global keyword:

```
class Log{
    protected $access;
    function Log(){
        global $access;
        $this->access = &$access;
    }
}
```

But you really should be passing the variable in the constructor:

```
class Log{
    protected $access;
    function Log($access){
        $this->access = &$access;
    }
    //...Then you have access to the access variable throughout the class:
    function test(){
        echo $this->access;
    }
}
```

Comment: Log() should be __construct() and both methods miss the public keyword.

Comment: Unless you want to be compatible with php 4 as well... then it would be log()

Comment: yeah, but then you couldnt have the protected keyword ;)

Comment: And php4 classes have properties as well (though all being public)

Comment: It has been quite a while since I used php4, but doesn't the function default to public if there is no keyword? (it does in php 5)