# Get access to global variable from construct php

Tags: php, global

I want to declare global variable in `__construct()` and access it from another public function.

```
class NewMineClass(){
   public function __construct(){
     global $goaway;
   }

   public function imHere(){
     $this->goaway;
   }
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variable inside a constructor with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927881/global-variable-inside-a-constructor-with-php)

Comment: `$this` refers to object variables.  If you must do this crazy crap and `$goaway` was declared in global scope then use `$GLOBALS`. Show more code like where `$goaway` comes from for better results.

Comment: class name should be without ()

Comment: When I read `global` in code, I often wonder why the person bothers to use classes at all. It's just wrong to do this... very, very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Meet [class properties](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). I think I better explain by an example:

```php
// Note that the class name needs no parenthesis 
class NewMineClass
{   
    // This is a class property, it's accessible within the class scope.
    // All the methods of this class can access it using `$this->goaway`.
    // If you want it to be accessible from outside the class, you need
    // to declare it as public instead of protected.
    protected $goaway;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->goaway = 'something i want to initialize in the constructor';
    }

    public function imHere()
    {
        echo $this->goaway;
        // Prints: something i want to initialize in the constructor
    }
}
```

I encourage you to read about PHP OOP concepts:

- [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
- [Class properties](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)
- [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)