# Php make variable in construct function available to other functions within controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller with __construct such as this one:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $auth = UserRepository::check();
        return $auth;
    }
```

what I want to be able to do is when I create a new function i.e.

```
public function test() {
  dd($auth);
}
```

However it says variable is not defined. How can I make it available to other function and not only construct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variable inside a constructor with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927881/global-variable-inside-a-constructor-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) keyword to set/get class variable

Set like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->auth = UserRepository::check();
}
```

And get like this

```
public function test() {
  return dd($this->auth);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`$auth` is a local variable to your constructor function. If you want methods in your class to use that variable, you need to assign your values to `$this->auth` rather than `$auth`. `$this` refers to the current object.